# java/Spring Inject a property value in pojo (non-managed)

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a pojo class in which fields are annotated with my custom annotation. It is a non-spring managed class.

```
public class ReportHeader {

    @Field(position = 1)
    private String jobName;

    ....
}
```

Now i want to pass the value of "**position**" attribute in annotation through a property file, something like below:

```
public class ReportHeader {

    @Field(position = "${read.my.position}")
    private String jobName;

    ....
}
```

How can i do it in a pojo class with or without spring?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not managed by Spring, you cannot expect it to inject anything.  It's an either/or proposition.

You can have Spring manage .properties and then give your `ReportHeader` a constructor to set its state using a `Properties` object that's passed in.

Comment: You mean i can have another class (spring managed) load properties in that and pass it to ReportHeader?

Comment: You can have Spring load a Properties file, yes.  You sound like you want to call new ReportHeader.  If that's true, find a way to get at the Properties you want from Spring and pass those to the ReportHeader.

Comment: But still how would i pass the value to the annotation attribute

Comment: You don't - you pass it to the constructor for ReportHeader when you call new to create it.  You'll get the Properties bean from the Spring bean factory and pass it along.